# external hard drive permissions

Tags: hard-drive

Dear Ubuntu Experts,

Would definitely appreciate some help.  I am using Ubuntu 14.04 that is on a partition.  Through the terminal I am trying to run a data processing script through an external hard drive and was given the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: RS_ICA.dr/scripts+logs/drB: Permission denied
```

Here is some info on drB:  Program File (type = `shell script (application/x-shellscript)`)

I did some background research and I believe my problem stems from how the external hard drive is mounted. However, I was not sure on how to go about unmounting and mounting my external while giving it new permissions.  Using `cat /etc/mtab`  I got for the external:

```
/dev/sdg1 /media/ryanbell/453Data fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Could someone please tell me if they think the problem is the permissions (possibly cause it is `default_permissions`?), and then how I might go about unmounting and mounting the external hard drive with new permissions?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you sure the script is executable?

Comment: @JacobVlijm the mount type is `fuseblk`. Almost certainly NTFS.

Comment: @muru ah, I overread the fact that the script was on the external drive...

Comment: Try doing 'test -x <file>' as root. If it returns positive, its a permission issue. If not, it's something else. Also try 'test -r <file>' and 'test -w <file> for read/write respectfully, also as root.